# using R to calculate mean and variance of amelia imputations using mi.meld (complete r novice)

Tags: r

I'm in a huge bind trying to use a program I've never used before... I am no computer scientist and do not have access to my regular statistics program and so have downloaded R.

I am trying to use `Amelia` and `mi.meld` to calculate the mean and variance of imputed datasets for a repeated measures study with two collection dates and 4 variables.

So, my dataset would look like this

```
study.id  assessment  variable1  variable 2 variable 3  variable 4
1             1           100       25         25           70
2             1            NA       10         11           15
3             1            14       50         NA           45
1             2            89       25         25           70
2             2            NA       10         11           15
3             2            18       50         NA           45
```

I want to:

a) create multiple imputed datasets using R (I accomplished this with the code below)

`a.out <- amelia(x = my.data, m=10, ts = "assessment", cs = "study.id")`

b) calculate mean and variance for variables at both time points across imputed datasets. I've attempted this with the code below

```
foo <-function(x, fcn) apply (x,2,fcn)
a.out.m <- lapply(a.out$imputations, foo, fcn = mean)
a.out.se <- lapply(a.out$imputations, foo, fcn = sd)) / sqrt(100)
a.meld <-mi.meld(q=a.out.m, se = a.out.se, byrow=TRUE)
```

BUT I'm having the following issues - some of my data is completely missing for a single participant at pre or post, so it is not imputed with the datasets (which is expected). However, this means that every time I try to calculate the mean or se of my imputed datasets, all I get back is "NA". Obviously this means my `mi.meld` function is not working either.

Comment: The problem with any calculation that includes an NA value is that result is always NA. Are those values really NA given you've used imputation?

Comment: I believe they're still "NA", as I get the following message when I perform the imputation: 

Warning: There are observations in the data that are completely missing. 
         These observations will remain unimputed in the final datasets

Comment: Remove rows that are completely missing, then impute.

Comment: Oh my god I can't believe I didn't think of that... Wow. Thank you, Edward!